# Return 'false' user if user does not enter argument for function?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a function like this:

```
def f(n)
 z = 0
 sum = 0
      while  z <= n 
      sum = sum + z
      z = z + 1
      end 
 return sum
 end
```

How do I return "false" when the user doesn't enter an argument for the function, i.e. when evaluating f()?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic length arguments in method and check if there is only one argument is exist like this:

```
 def f(*args)
   if args.length == 1
     n = args.first
     z = 0
     sum = 0
     while  z <= n
       sum = sum + z
       z = z + 1
     end
     return sum
   else
     return false
   end
 end
```

Comment: Oh cool, that's a neat trick. What is the function of the asterisk before args, if I may ask?

Comment: It holds all the arguments as an array. So if you pass something like f(1,2,3) then args equals to [1,2,3] because of the asterisk. You should use asterisk for the variable length arguments in method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for `n` , like this

```
def f(n = nil)
 return false if n.nil?
 z = 0
 sum = 0
      while  z <= n 
        sum = sum + z
        z = z + 1
      end 
 return
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks almost like you're setting the variable n to nil in the brackets--which would return false all the time. Why doesn't that happen here?

Comment: `n`  would not be nil when you passed a value to the function

Comment: Note that this only works when `nil` is not a valid argument value. Otherwise, if there are no invalid argument values, you need to resort to the `def f(n = (n_not_set = true; nil))` trick.